# All possible combinations of columns in dataframe -pandas/python

Tags: pandas, combinations

I'm trying to take one dataframe and create another, with all possible combinations of the columns and the difference between the corresponding values, i.e on 11-apr column AB should be (B-A)= 0 etc.

e.g, starting with

```
        Dt              A           B           C          D
        11-apr          1           1           1          1
        10-apr          2           3           1          2
```

how do I get a new frame that looks like this:

[image: desired result]

I have come across the below post, but have not been able to transpose this to work for columns.

[Aggregate all dataframe row pair combinations using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777702/aggregate-all-dataframe-row-pair-combinations-using-pandas)

Comment: Any thoughts on how to do this for 3 columns, so let's say i want to do 2*B - A - C in the above example?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use:

```
from itertools import combinations
df = df.set_index('Dt')

cc = list(combinations(df.columns,2))
df = pd.concat([df[c[1]].sub(df[c[0]]) for c in cc], axis=1, keys=cc)
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
print (df)
        AB  AC  AD  BC  BD  CD
Dt                            
11-apr   0   0   0   0   0   0
10-apr   1  -1   0  -2  -1   1
```

Comment: Thanks for this, works perfectly. Any thoughts on how to modify this for 3 combinations, e.g ABC, ABD, BCD etc and then rather than (B-A) having 2* B - C - A.

Comment: do you think `cc = list(combinations(df.columns,3))` ?

Comment: and then `df.columns = df.columns.map('-'.join)` ?

Comment: I've got the list working no problem, but on pd.concat([df[c[2]].sub(df[c[1]]) I'm struggling to work in a third reference.

Comment: Hmmm, so need `df = pd.concat([2 * df[c[2]] - df[c[1]] - df[c[0]] for c in cc], axis=1, keys=cc)`, right?

Comment: or maybe `df = pd.concat([2 * df[c[1]] - df[c[2]] - df[c[0]] for c in cc], axis=1, keys=cc)`

Comment: How can I do the same with all more variables (more combinations) AND add the numbers (or strings alternatively) instead of subtract them? e.g. A B C D E  AB AC AD ..... ABCDE ? @jezrael

Answer (score 9):

Make sure your index is `Dt`

```
df = df.set_index('Dt')
```

Using `numpy`s `np.tril_indices` and slicing
See below for explanation of `np.triu_indices`

```
v = df.values

i, j = np.tril_indices(len(df.columns), -1)
```

We can create a `pd.MultiIndex` for the columns.  This makes it more generalizable for column names that are longer than one character.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    v[:, i] - v[:, j],
    df.index,
    [df.columns[j], df.columns[i]]
)

        A     B  A  B  C
        B  C  C  D  D  D
Dt                      
11-apr  0  0  0  0  0  0
10-apr  1 -1 -2  0 -1  1
```

But we can also do

```
pd.DataFrame(
    v[:, i] - v[:, j],
    df.index,
    df.columns[j] + df.columns[i]
)

        AB  AC  BC  AD  BD  CD
Dt                            
11-apr   0   0   0   0   0   0
10-apr   1  -1  -2   0  -1   1
```

---

***`np.tril_indices` explained***

This is a `numpy` function that returns two arrays that when used together, provide the locations of a lower triangle of a square matrix.  This is handy when doing manipulations of all combinations of things as this lower triangle represents all combinations of one axis of a matrix with the other.

Consider the dataframe `d` for illustration

```
d = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy')).reshape(-1, 5))
d

   0  1  2  3  4
0  a  b  c  d  e
1  f  g  h  i  j
2  k  l  m  n  o
3  p  q  r  s  t
4  u  v  w  x  y
```

The triangle indices, when looked at like coordinate pairs, looks like this

```
i, j = np.tril_indices(5, -1)
list(zip(i, j))

[(1, 0),
 (2, 0),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 0),
 (3, 1),
 (3, 2),
 (4, 0),
 (4, 1),
 (4, 2),
 (4, 3)]
```

I can manipulate `d`s values with `i` and `j`

```
d.values[i, j] = 'z'
d

   0  1  2  3  4
0  a  b  c  d  e
1  z  g  h  i  j
2  z  z  m  n  o
3  z  z  z  s  t
4  z  z  z  z  y
```

And you can see it targeted just that lower triangle

***naive time test***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Itertools` module should help you to create the required combinations/permutations.

```
from itertools import combinations

# Creating a new pd.DataFrame
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)

# list of columns
columns = df.columns

# Create all combinations of length 2 . eg. AB, BC, etc.
for combination in combinations(columns, 2):
    combination_string = "".join(combination)
    new_df[combination_string] = df[combination[1]]-df[combination[0]]
    print new_df


         AB  AC  AD  BC  BD  CD
Dt                            
11-apr   0   0   0   0   0   0
10-apr   1  -1   0  -2  -1   1
```

Comment: Although slower than Languitar's answer from above, this is much more readable. Thank you @Nipun for your excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.combinations` will help you:

```
import itertools
pd.DataFrame({'{}{}'.format(a, b): df[a] - df[b] for a, b in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2)})
```

Which results in:

```
        AB  AC  AD  BC  BD  CD
Dt                            
11-apr   0   0   0   0   0   0
10-apr  -1   1   0   2   1  -1
```

Comment: This one works well if you have additional conditions such as df = pd.DataFrame({'{}{}'.format(a, b): df[a] & df[b] for a, b in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2) if (df[a] & df[b]).any() }). The column labels won't get messed up like the previous answers.