# All possible combinations of 3 columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

This is a follow up to a previous question here

[combinations of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347939/all-possible-combinations-of-columns-in-dataframe-pandas-python)

I'm trying to take one dataframe and create another, with all possible combinations of 3 columns together and the difference between the corresponding values, i.e on 11-apr column ABC should be (2B -A - C)= 0, then 2*B-A-D = 0 and so on etc.

e.g, starting with

```
        Dt              A           B           C          D
        11-apr          1           1           1          1
        10-apr          2           3           1          2
```

how do I get a new frame that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The same method applies here as the answer provided by jezrael in your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347939/all-possible-combinations-of-columns-in-dataframe-pandas-python) - you just need to tweek the `concat` part to the following: `df = pd.concat([(2*df[c[1]]).sub(df[c[0]]+df[c[2]]) for c in cc], axis=1, keys=cc)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need:

```
cc = list(combinations(df.columns,3))

df = pd.concat([df[c[1]].mul(2).sub(df[c[2]]).sub(df[c[0]]) for c in cc], axis=1, keys=cc)
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
print (df)
        ABC  ABD  ACD  BCD
Dt                        
11-apr    0    0    0    0
10-apr    3    2   -2   -3
```