# Length of values does not match length of index for exactly same length of index and values

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, match

I have a simple dataset with an equal length of values and index, but keep getting the value error. It run ok yesterday, but got errors when I added the final line in.

```
df={"date":[2018,2019],'x1': [1, 2], 'x2': [3, 4], 'y1': [8, 6],'y2': [7, 8], 'y3': [9, 2]} 
df=pd.DataFrame(data=df)
baseyear=min(df["date"])
df["t"]=df["date"]-baseyear+1
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y').dt.year
df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
col=df.columns.to_list()
df[sq+"sq"]=[0.5*(df[sq]**2) for sq in col]
df[sq+"t"]=[(df[sq]*df["t"] if sq !="t" else df["t"]) for sq in col]
```

Comment: what is df[sq] ?

Comment: It's a new variable calculated by col**2, means square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can processing all columns together, [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and add to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), for second is similar idea with remove `t`:

```
df = df.join((0.5*(df[col]**2)).add_suffix('sq'))

df = df.join(df[col.difference(['t'])].mul(df["t"], axis=0).add_suffix('t'))
#last added tt column same like t
df['tt'] = df['t']

print (df)
      x1  x2  y1  y2  y3  t  x1sq  x2sq  y1sq  y2sq  y3sq  tsq  x1t  x2t  y1t  \
date                                                                            
2018   1   3   8   7   9  1   0.5   4.5  32.0  24.5  40.5  0.5    1    3    8   
2019   2   4   6   8   2  2   2.0   8.0  18.0  32.0   2.0  2.0    4    8   12   

      y2t  y3t  tt  
date                
2018    7    9   1  
2019   16    4   2
```

Your solution should be working with for loops, but if many columns performance should be worse:

```
col=df.columns.to_list()

for sq in col:
    df[sq+"sq"]= 0.5*(df[sq]**2)
for sq in col:
    df[sq+"t"]= (df[sq]*df["t"] if sq !="t" else df["t"])

print (df)
      x1  x2  y1  y2  y3  t  x1sq  x2sq  y1sq  y2sq  y3sq  tsq  x1t  x2t  y1t  \
date                                                                            
2018   1   3   8   7   9  1   0.5   4.5  32.0  24.5  40.5  0.5    1    3    8   
2019   2   4   6   8   2  2   2.0   8.0  18.0  32.0   2.0  2.0    4    8   12   

      y2t  y3t  tt  
date                
2018    7    9   1  
2019   16    4   2
```

EDIT: Solution for multiple by combinations of columns:

```
from  itertools import combinations


df={"date":[2018,2019],'x1': [1, 2], 'x2': [3, 4], 'y1': [8, 6],'y2': [7, 8], 'y3': [9, 2]} 
df=pd.DataFrame(data=df)
baseyear=min(df["date"])
df["t"]=df["date"]-baseyear+1
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y').dt.year
df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
```

---

```
col = df.columns
col_without_t = col.difference(['t'])


df1 = df.join((0.5*(df[col]**2)).add_suffix('sq'))

df1 = df1.join(df1[col_without_t].mul(df1["t"], axis=0).add_suffix('t'))
df1['tt'] = df1['t']


cc = list(combinations(col,2))
#if want columns without t
#cc = list(combinations(col_without_t,2))
df2 = pd.concat([df[c[1]].mul(df[c[0]]) for c in cc], axis=1, keys=cc) 
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(''.join)

df = df.join(df2)

print (df)
      x1  x2  y1  y2  y3  t  x1x2  x1y1  x1y2  x1y3  ...  x2y1  x2y2  x2y3  \
date                                                 ...                     
2018   1   3   8   7   9  1     3     8     7     9  ...    24    21    27   
2019   2   4   6   8   2  2     8    12    16     4  ...    24    32     8   

      x2t  y1y2  y1y3  y1t  y2y3  y2t  y3t  
date                                        
2018    3    56    72    8    63    7    9  
2019    8    48    12   12    16   16    4  

[2 rows x 21 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks. The first solution got an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'difference'. The second solution works, but I will have a lot of cross calculations, faster run time would be preferred.

Comment: @S Hendricks In first solution change `col=df.columns.to_list()` to `col=df.columns` for working correct only.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I actually need all columns in col to multiply each other and create new variables from it, except for the squares taking 0.5. Any ideas?

Comment: @ jezrael I tried    ``` for key in col:     df = df.join(df[col.difference([key])].mul(df[key], axis=0).add_suffix(key))```
it creates duplicated results, like "x1y1" and "y1x1"

Comment: @SHendricks  can you be more specific? what should be expecting output?

Comment: @SHendricks - Do you need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43348187/2901002) ?

Comment: quite similar. I tried what you recommended in another  post, but got an error 't' with axis=1. ```col=df.columns.tolist()
    cc = list(combinations(df.columns,2))
    for col in col:
        df = pd.concat([df[c[1]].mul(df[c[0]]) for c in cc], axis=1, keys=cc)
    df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)```

Comment: @ jezreal, the results I want, for example, x1,x2,y1,y2,y3,t, 0.5x1x1, x1y1,x1y2....and 0.5 for all square terms.

Comment: @ jezreal, ```df = pd.concat([df[c[1]].mul(df[c[0]]) for c in cc], axis=1, keys=cc)
    df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join) ```, this works but removed all original variables which I also need to keep. I know I can create another dataframe then join later, but it will be nice to have it in one line? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @SHendricks - I think I understand,

Comment: @SHendricks - Answer was edited. I think second paragraph solution cannot used here