# Efficient and faster way to get dataframe column permutations(?) as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, data-science

If we have a dataframe with 3 columns a b c

and i want to add columns to it in a way that we get:
a b c a/b a/c/ b/a b/c c/a c/b
,

the easiest way I can think of is

```py
column_list = list(df.columns)
for i in range(len(column_list)):
    p1 = column_list[i]
    for j in range(len(columns_list)):
        p2 = column_list[j]
        df[p1+'/'+p2] = df[p1]/df[p2]
```

But is there a faster and more effiecient way I can do this?

I have a task where I have to do this for 1000 parameters,
doing by the above way takes a lot of time.

Any Help will be greatly Appreciated

Comment: in dupe solution instead subtracton use division.

Comment: @jezrael Sorry, couldn't get you, I didn't use subtraction anywhere here right?

Comment: In linked dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347939/all-possible-combinations-of-columns-in-dataframe-pandas-python