# square matrix of pairwise min() values in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

What is the best way to create a matrix which has pairwise min() values?
I have data with 2 columns:

```
prod price
a     28
b     65
c     26
```

I need to create a matrix where each value is the min(price1, price2)

```
   a    b     c
a  NA  28    26
b  28  NA    26
c  26  26    NA
```

I will later extract upper or lower triangle from this. Is there any specific library to do this in python?

Comment: This will help : [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777702/aggregate-all-dataframe-row-pair-combinations-using-pandas)

Comment: What do you mean by *best way*?