# Adjusted spearman rank correlation on paired samples of SA indices

Tags: python, pandas, ranking

I want to apply the following adjusted spearman rank correlation (for convergence checking of sobol sensitivity indices) on the following dataframe, as suggested in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364815216300251?via%3Dihub. (convergence of input factor ranking). In the formule i are the parameters (a, b or c) and j/k are the sample number (so 1, 2, 3 or 4 in this case).

[image]

The example dataframe consists of 3 parameters (a,b,c) and their sobol sensitivity index (S_a, S_b, S_c) and rank (R_a, R_b, R_c) is given for 4 samples:

**Initial df:**

```
      S_a    S_b    S_c    R_a   R_b   R_c
1     0.3    0.4    0.2      2     1     3
2     0.5    0.3    0.2      1     2     3
3     0.6    0.3    0.1      1     2     3
4     0.6    0.3    0.1      1     2     3
```

The formula states, I should get a spearman coefficient for all possible pairs of sample outcomes. This means for this dataset I should get a spearman correlation for the combinations (1_2) (1_3) (2_3) (1_4) (2_4) (3_4). -> (1_1) is not a legal pair combination, neither is (2_1) as it is equal to (1_2). Therefore the output dataframe should look like for the initial dataframe:

**Desired df:**

```
combination(j,k)       spearman(j,k)
            1_2                 ...
            1_3                 ...
            2_3                 ...
            1_4                 ...
            2_4                 ...
            3_4                 ...
```

I'm struggling with the code however.I've come untill the point where I should sum all terms in the above equation.
**Code**

```
import pandas as pd  

df = pd.DataFrame({ "ID": ['n1','n2','n3','n4'],
                   "S_a": [0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6], 
                   "S_b": [0.4,0.3,0.3,0.3],
                  "S_c": [0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1], 
                   "R_a": [2,1,1,1], 
                   "R_b": [1,2,2,2],
                  "R_c": [3,3,3,3]})  
print(df)
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)

a, b = map(list, zip(*combinations(df.index, 2)))
d = pd.concat([df.loc[a].reset_index(), df.loc[b].reset_index()],keys=['a', 'b'], axis=1)
d.set_index([('a', 'ID'), ('b', 'ID')]).rename_axis(['a', 'b'])
print(d)

# S_max -----
S_max = d.loc[:,d.columns.get_level_values(1).isin({"S_a", "S_b", "S_c"})]
S_max = S_max.max(level=1, axis=1)**2
S_max['S_sum'] = S_max.sum(axis=1)
print(S_max)

# R_abs -----
R_abs = d.loc[:,d.columns.get_level_values(1).isin({"R_a", "R_b", "R_c"})]
print(R_abs)
R_abs = R_abs['a'].sub(R_abs['b'], level=1, axis=1).abs()
print(R_abs)

# ID_sum -----
ID_sum = d.loc[:,d.columns.get_level_values(1).isin({"ID"})]
ID_sum = ID_sum.reindex(['b','a'], level=0, axis=1)
ID_sum = ID_sum.apply(lambda x : ''.join(x.astype(str)),1)
ID_sum.columns = ['ID']

print(ID_sum)

# resulting matrix -----
result = S_max
result["ID"] = ID_sum
result = result.merge(R_abs, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
print(result)

result['spearman'] = sum(x.mul(y.div(z)) for x,y,z in zip([result['R_a'], result['R_b'], result['R_c']],[result['S_a'], result['S_b'], result['S_c']], [result['S_sum'], result['S_sum'], result['S_sum']]))
print(result)
...
```

Comment: Can you post all the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregate all dataframe row pair combinations using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777702/aggregate-all-dataframe-row-pair-combinations-using-pandas)

Comment: Thanks, the link was useful but only a part of what I'm looking for. I've added all the code I had. I calculated all the terms for each pair. Now I only have to use them in the equation I think. However, the code could be more elegant...

Comment: So now, you just want instead of summing, to calculate spearman?

Comment: No, I figured it out already. I think I got what I was looking for. The code above gives me the outcome of the formula for the example dataframe. Thanks for the suggested page, that helped a bit. :-)